# TextField and Button not appearing inside of a Container View?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I am new to iOS development and I am wondering if anyone is able to help me out.  I have a view container that holds two text fields and a button as follows:

[image]

When I run inside of a simulator, I am only able to see the dark grey background of the container and none of the text fields are showing nor is the button, ex:


[image]

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what your code is actually doing, but my first guess is that it looks like the view isn't actually being loaded? Can you show a screenshot of the actual segue connections between the view and its content Xib? Other possibility is that you haven't set the view to load the Xib.

Comment: I would start by printing out the textFields frames, and their container's frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` just to see where they are actually being told to be placed in the view. Make sure all the size constraints are set properly

Comment: @brandonscript Oh jeez, thanks for your help.  Turns out that the view was not being loaded.  Thanks man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, it looks like the view isn't being loaded. Make sure you've connected all the Xib components properly and ensure the view is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the container view? It looks to me like it's being covered by the map view. Try selecting the container view and then selecting "bring to front from the editing menu's "arrange" sub-menu.